# How to create UIImage from CPTPlotSymbol?

Tags: ios, core-plot

I am new to `Core-Plot`, and here is my problem.

I created my `Graph` using `ScatterPlot` class. And my plot symbol creation data source method is:

```
- (CPTPlotSymbol*)symbolForScatterPlot:(CPTScatterPlot *)plot recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    CPTPlotSymbol *symbol = [[CPTPlotSymbol alloc]init];
    if (index %2 == 0)
    {
        symbol.symbolType = CPTPlotSymbolTypeDiamond;
        symbol.fill = [CPTFill fillWithColor:[CPTColor redColor]];
        symbol.size = CGSizeMake(10, 10);
        return symbol;
    }
    else
    {
        symbol.symbolType = CPTPlotSymbolTypeEllipse;
        symbol.fill = [CPTFill fillWithColor:[CPTColor orangeColor]];
        symbol.size = CGSizeMake(15, 15);
        return symbol;
    }
}
```

And when i select any plot symbol from my `scatter plot`, i want to convert that selected plot symbol to `UIImage`, because after converting into image i want to drag the image from the source place to any other place with that `plotspace`.

I implemented delegate method to get the selected plot symbol from my scatter plot, the code is

```
- (void)scatterPlot:(CPTScatterPlot *)plot plotSymbolWasSelectedAtRecordIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    CPTPlotSymbol *selectedSymbol = [plot plotSymbolForRecordIndex:index];
    NSLog(@"%@", selectedSymbol);
}
```

from above code i am getting my selected plot symbol object. but from here i don't know how to covert this plot symbol object to `UIImage`. if any one guide me it will be great or there is any other better way to solve my problem means kindly help me in that way also. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `-renderAsVectorInContext:atPoint:scale:` method to draw the symbol into a `CGContext`. Create a context, draw the symbol into it, and use `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()` to create a `UIImage`.

Comment: but how can i get the `CPTPlotSymbol` fill pattern (ie, fillColor, fillPattern, fillImage) design to draw my context as same as symbol.

Comment: It's all drawn as part of the symbol.

Comment: How to insert a `CPTSymbol` at run time in `ScatterPlot`?

Comment: Call `-insertDataAtIndex:numberOfRecords:` on the plot to add another data point to the plot. It will query the datasource to get the new values.